# Is there a way to check the strength of internet connection in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to upload some multimedia files(Images, Audio and Videos) to my server and I only want to upload these files if there is a stable internet connection. Is there a concrete way to achieve this?

Comment: hey @fritz-playmaker did you find anything for check the strength of internet connection, if yes Let me know what is it.

Comment: check connection strength using this package,https://pub.dev/packages/wifi

Comment: @fritz-playmaker I hope you figured for a solution I am also stucking at the same problem

Answer (score 1):

One year after, there is a new (Mar. 31, 2020) package that solves this need.
Check at https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test#-readme-tab-

Answer (score 0):

You can use dart's [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package which is maintained by Google team, according to its [documentation](http://This%20plugin%20allows%20Flutter%20apps%20to%20discover%20network%20connectivity%20and%20configure%20themselves%20accordingly.%20It%20can%20distinguish%20between%20cellular%20vs%20WiFi%20connection.%20This%20plugin%20works%20for%20iOS%20and%20Android.) :

"This plugin allows Flutter apps to discover network connectivity and configure themselves accordingly. It can distinguish between cellular vs WiFi connection. This plugin works for iOS and Android."

This way you can use the plugin to determine whether the user is connected over Wifi and if so upload the data, otherwise not to upload and wait for connection type change.

Comment: That's awesome. But i am looking for the ability to check for the strength of the internet connection

Comment: Currently there no way to check that but I guess you have to adapt other way like the way I already provided or to upload some test data routinely ( 500KB - 1 MB) and measure the time it took, good luck..

Comment: But, connectivity doesn't provide any method or property to identify whether internet strength is weak or strong, right?

Comment: Connectivity package just tells what's connected or not connected. It doesn't provide info about network speed.

Comment: This doesn't work for checking the strength of the network. The plugin returned true for a GSM-strength network. If you were to do any internet operation with this speed, you will likely encounter an error

Answer (score 0):

there no way to check that currently . but You can try to upload or download a file and calculate the time it took